# How do i test nodejs module.exports function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, chai

trying to test nodejs module.export function that will return based on request but it throws below error any idea what is implemented wrong here its expecting error >

v1Transform.js

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {


     try {
        const validateResponse = responseHandler(req.drugPriceResponse);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof AppError) {
          res.status(error.response.status).send(error.response.payload);
        } else {
          res.status(500).send(defaultErrorResponse);
        }
      }
    }
```

main.test.js

```
describe('v1Transform()', () => {
  it('should return error if accounts are ommitted', () => {
    try {
          v1Transform(req);
        } catch (error) {
          expect(error.response).to.deep.equal({
            status: 500,
            payload: {
              'status': 500,
              'title': 'Internal Server Error',
              'detail': 'Accounts are not valid'
            }
          });
        }
});
});
```

Error

```
  1) v1Transform()
       should return error if prices are ommitted:
     AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal { Object (status, payload) }
```

Comment: So `v1Transform` is the same as `responseHandler`? It's really unclear to me how the two files are related.

Comment: @Bergi v1Transform is main.js whole file then we have further validation in `responseHandler`  that is returning the error i am testing.

Comment: You defined your function as async, but didn't put the await keyword before calling v1Transform()